# How to fetch data from html/templates

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

I am using html5 geolocation to get the current location of each user and then store it to the database. 
I dont know how to get the current location without using form or input method in html then post it to the server.

```
<form method="post" id="geo_form">
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="lon" name="lon" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click">
</form>

<script>
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById("lat").value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("lon").value = position.coords.longitude;   
    }

    getLocation()

<script>
```

Then in in database, I can get the geolocation by using post:

```
def post(self):
    lat = float(self.request.get("lat"))
    lon = float(self.request.get("lon"))
```

The probem is I want to make the current location is updated everytime the user refresh the page. Is there any way to do it?

I know I can use getDocumentbyId.submit() but I want to make this page the main page which user can get local feed based on their location. So, If I use getDocumentbyId.submit() in this html it will go infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When serving a request, GAE automatically inserts a response header `X-AppEngine-CityLatLong` which contain latitude and longitude based on the IP address of the client request.

You can access the header with something like :

```
location = self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-CityLatLong')
```

More info here : http://rominirani.com/2012/04/25/appengine-location-detection-update-x-appengine-country-and-more/

Comment: It is not working on dev server (localhost) but after I read in other source it is only working on deployed apps. Thanks for telling me about that google headers.